# DataTables Pagination buttons appear on 2nd page but not in 1st

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using `DataTables` with customize pagination buttons. I am using CSS to set the pagination buttons as the background property. Buttons show up properly on the 2nd page but on the first page 1st and Previous buttons disappear but when I click on the Next buttons then the button appears for the First and Previous.

First Page (on page load)

[image]

Second Page (All buttons appear)

[image]

Third Page (Buttons disappear again)

[image]

I want them to be there all the time. How can I achieve this.

JQuery

```
var table = $('#esignTable').DataTable({"sDom": '<"top"flp>rt<"bottom"i><"clear">',
      pagingType: 'input',
      pageLength: 10,
      language: {
        "sEmptyTable": " ",
        oPaginate: {
            "sNext": ' ',
            "sPrevious": ' ',
            "sFirst": ' ',
            "sLast": ' ',
        }
      }   
    });
```

CSS

```
.next {
   background: url(../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg);
}

.previous { 
   background: url(../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg);
}

.first { 
   background: url(../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg);
}

.last {
   background: url(../images/integration/FastRight.jpg);
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong in my CSS

Thanks

Comment: This is quite common in pagination, but if you want to change it I think you have to supply your own html and use the datatables functions to go back/forth. https://datatables.net/reference/api/page()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `!important` to your rules or use more specific CSS rules.

For example:

```
.next {
   background: url(../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg) !important;
}

.previous { 
   background: url(../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg) !important;
}

.first { 
   background: url(../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg) !important;
}

.last {
   background: url(../images/integration/FastRight.jpg) !important;
}
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/7bxwhvzv/3/) for code and demonstration.